# Java - Referring Enum (number value) in database using Hibernate (HBM)

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hbm

I am trying to convert the text field in a giant Postgres table which has the values like (1, 2, 3, 4, __ALL) into an enum. The plan is to update the text field to an enum in the database.

I understand that I can't do Enum as follows in Java;

```
public enum MyEnum {
 1,2,3,4; 
}
```

I can either do as;

```
public enum MyEnum {
  _1,_2,_3,_4;
}
```

Or:

```
public enum QuartileNumber {
   ONE("1"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), __ALL("__ALL");
}
```

My hibernate mapping looks like this;

```
<property name="quartileNumber" column="quartile_number">
      <type name="com.altosresearch.model.PostgreSQLEnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">com.altosresearch.model.QuartileNumber</param>
        <param name="type">12</param>
      </type>
</property>
```

Using this mapping and my Java enum (QuartileNumber);

QuartileNumbers.valueOf("__ALL") - returns '_ALL' (the expected enumClass of com.altosresearch.model.QuartileNumber)

QuartileNumbers.valueOf("ONE") - returns 'ONE' (which will be obviously rejected in the database as it doesn't match one of the DB enum values (1, 2, 3, 4, __ALL).

So, I am able to insert correctly only the value '__ALL' into the table. Need suggestions to insert values 1, 2, 3, 4 as well here. Thanks!

Note: Trying to use the same existing values in the database ('1','2','3','4','__ALL') to avoid the code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can help here is to use the AttributeConverter for the Enum.

Here is a link from Thorben Janssen
https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/

how to save in the DB values : 1,2,3,4,__ALL from the Enum definition:

```
public enum QuartileNumber {
   ONE("1"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), __ALL("__ALL");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the AttributeConverter. It helped! Ours is legacy code and uses Hibernate’s UserType interface and couldn't mix the annotations. The above example helped to implement the same in our case. I will share the detailed implementation soon.